# Find MAX of a collection of results in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want a formula to tell me the highest/MAX value of these three CountIF formulas

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*Sm 57*")     which equals 7

=COUNTIF(B1:B10,"*Sm 57*")     which equals 5

=COUNTIF(C1:C10,"*Sm 57*")     which equals 3
```

I want the formula to give me an answer of 7

Answer (score 1):

You can place the three Countif() functions inside a Max() function.

```
=max(COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Sm 57"),COUNTIF(B1:B10,"Sm 57"),COUNTIF(C1:C10,"Sm 57"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much

That worked

One more question,
What about if the first COUNTIF was
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Sm 57")+COUNTIF(A1:A10,"57")+COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Sm57")

Comment: I figured it out

Thank you so much, You're my hero

Here is what I got

=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Sm 57")+COUNTIF(A1:A10,"57")+COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Sm57"),COUNTIF(B1:B10,"Sm 57")+COUNTIF(B1:B10,"57")+COUNTIF(B1:B10,"Sm57"),COUNTIF(C1:C10,"Sm 57")+COUNTIF(C1:C10,"57")+COUNTIF(C1:C10,"Sm57”))

Thank you

Comment: If that helped, please mark the post as the answer, as explained in the [Tour]